# Where should dependencies show for grouped checkboxes? After the selection or after the entire group?

Tags: information-architecture, checkboxes, best-practice, fields

I am looking to set a system wide standard for the design of dependencies for grouped checkboxes. Are there any best practices for doing it one way over the other?

In my examples the first 3 checkboxes in the group have dependencies.

**Right below the checkbox that is checked:**
[image]

**Below the entire checkbox group:**
[image]

Comment: As a general rule it is always better to give feedback as soon as possible, as close as possible. This makes it easier for users to follow the cause-effect relationships.

Comment: What is the context? Do users choose multiple races? Can you please explain what the user is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Based on some of the basic rules like "Logical objects should be grouped together", IMO first option is lot better.

In second option - if someone wants to deselect one of previous selected checkboxes one must count which one is it in the list.

If you take first option, and place a bit of additional margin between groups (group = checkbox + 1 input field), you should have clear UI / UX.

Answer (score 1):

For this example I would refer to the [law of proximity](https://lawsofux.com/law-of-proximity)

> "Objects that are near, or proximate to each other, tend to be grouped
>   together."

A more in depth look at this law and how it is applied to GUI you can see on [Nielsen Norman website](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/closeness-of-actions-and-objects-gui/)

> "When buttons, drop-downs, checkboxes, or other actionable GUI
>   elements are too far away from the objects they act on, people don't
>   see them."

In which case version 1 of your design is a better solution.

Hope this helps. Cheers!